# .idmin() and .idmax() in a Series not working

Tags: python, pandas, attributes

I am learning about python/pandas attributes in a Series. I can get it to display the min and max values, but I want to display the min and max index values and I get an error message.

```
google.min()
```

49.95

```
google.max()
```

782.22

```
google.idmin()
```

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent
>   call last)  in 
>   ----> 1 google.idmin(True)
>
> /opt/anaconda3/envs/pandas_playground/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py
>   in **getattr**(self, name)    5272             if
>   self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):    5273
>   return self[name]
>   -> 5274             return object.**getattribute**(self, name)    5275     5276     def **setattr**(self, name: str, value) -> None:
>
> AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'idmin'

Comment: What version of pandas are you running? Can you post result of this `print(pd.__version__)`

Comment: 1.0.3 do I need to update something?

Answer (score 13):

After some searching, I found I was simply using the wrong methods.

idxmin and idxmax work just fine.

```
google.idxmax()
```

3011

```
google.idxmin()
```

11

Comment: I can't believe your answer worked for me too :D :D , I missed the letter x.

Comment: I also didn't realize that I missed the letter x, I was trying `idmax` instead of `idxmax` :-(